# How to query objects(databases, tables) which were not accessed between two dates?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

how to query objects(databases, tables) which were not accessed between two dates?
I am using this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.ACCESS_HISTORY 
WHERE DIRECT_OBJECTS_ACCESSED ::TEXT ='[]' 
AND BASE_OBJECTS_ACCESSED ::TEXT ='[]' 
AND QUERY_START_TIME between '2021-04-01' and GetDATE()
```

I am not sure if it is correct. But I also want a column 'object name' which will show the database, tables, etc.

Answer (score 0):

All objects queried:

```sql
with all_objects as (
    select obj.value:objectName::string object_name, query_start_time
    from snowflake.account_usage.access_history 
      , table(flatten(base_objects_accessed)) obj
    where object_name is not null
)


select object_name, min(query_start_time), max(query_start_time)
from all_objects
```

With that, now you need to remove all objects queried during the time you are interested in. Then you will have all objects, minus the objects during that interval:

```sql
with all_objects as (
    select obj.value:objectName::string object_name, query_start_time
    from snowflake.account_usage.access_history 
      , table(flatten(base_objects_accessed)) obj
    where object_name is not null
)


select object_name, min(query_start_time), max(query_start_time)
from all_objects
where object_name not in (
    select object_name
    from all_objects
    where query_start_time between '2021-04-01' and '2021-05-01'
    group by 1
)
group by 1
```

Ref: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/access_history.html